# How to supress Powershell window when using the -File option

Tags: python, powershell, popen, windowless

I'm calling Powershell like so:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -noninteractive -nologo -file "C:\Users\dummy\Documents\dev\powershell\samples\test.ps1"
```

I'm calling it from a python script, but the same problem can be observed if called via a shortcut. I thought the `-NonInteractive` flag would cause Poweshell to execute in a hidden window, but it doesn't. Is there a way of supressing the console window when calling Powershell from an external application?

## Solution based on Johannes Rössel suggestion

```
import subprocess
st_inf = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
st_inf.dwFlags = st_inf.dwFlags | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
subprocess.Popen(["notepad"], startupinfo=st_inf)
```

Comment: fYI: I think `-NonInteractive` just says: *don't emit prompts.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass appropriate arguments to [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863(v=VS.85).aspx) or [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle(v=VS.90).aspx) to suppress the console window.

However, PowerShell also has a `-WindowStyle` parameter which you can set to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I had no luck with `-WindowStyle Hidden`, because a console window appeared every time for a while.

That's why I use a helper exe called PsRun.exe that does exactly that. You can download source and exe file [Run scheduled tasks with WinForm GUI in PowerShell](http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=run-scheduled-tasks-with-winform-gui-in-powershell). I use it for scheduled tasks.

(Note that -windowstyle parameter is available only for V2.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `-WindowStyle Hidden`. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315276.aspx).